# Magento 2: The newly added column does not appear in the product export csv file

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-ee

When we export Magento products, in the CSV there is one column **related_skus**. I have added one column with the same name, **accessories_skus**. But when I export to the staging server on the live server, "**accessories_skus**" does not come in a csv file.

I have faced the same issue on my local system as well, but after rebooting my local system, the new column "**accessories_skus**" came in a csv file. because when the system reboots, my consumer queue is reset, and on the live site, we can't reboot the server. So please let me know if anyone has a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil,

There is multiple possibility.

1. You will have a multiple running Queue on the Magento.
2. You can run the export Queue manually using below command.

> php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Pragnesh yes i have try to run that command but not getting as excepted results. yeah i also try to download csv file directly without putting on queue and it work perfect.